# python django database synch

Tags: python, database, django, synchronization

I use django in project. I have many cron jobs which operate with database. I want to replace cron jobs on other machine and synchronize processed data with main server. But my host provider doesnt allow external connections to db. How to organize sync. best way? I know what i can pass it via POST request with my own written protocol, buy may be better solution exsists or lib for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are *all* external connections blocked? If you can get an `rsync` daemon to run in the machine you can push (sync, rather) the data from other machines to master and have master process it. This will involve adding some kind of daemon process at the master.

If *all* connections are indeed blocked you will have to resort to POST or the more tedious one of receiving email attachments and processing them.

Side note: you should think of switching providers post-haste!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an awful lot of work for negligible little gain. I would suggest trying an Amazon EC2 micro image and run Django on that for $0.03 US per hour (doesn't appear to be updated on the [pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) just yet but it is in the AWS web console). Then you can do what ever you want.

How does the Web hosting provider block outgoing connections? Can you put an external database server on a popular port like 53, 80, 143, etc., and see if you can connect that way?

Comment: i have no access to this, the external connections a blocked and hoster said what it is not possible to open it. I knew what i can change hosting, but i don't want to do this now.